# Running python programs on android

Tags: android, python, qpython

First of all I apologize that I am not a programmer and my IT knowledge is limited.
I have written a very basic python program which runs on windows.
I just want to run it on my android phone.
I checked with Qpython app for android and I could not figure out what to do with that.
Please let me know how I can run this program on my android phone.
Please describe the solution keeping in mind that I don't understand much of the IT jargon.

Answer (score 1):

Run python program in android with Qpython:

> Create program and run it:

- Go to Editor.
- Write Your Script.
- Tap Save icon. ('4th icon' at bottom)
- Tap Run. ('Arrow icon' in middle at bottom)

Script will run and output/errors will be shown in logfile in notification bar.

> Run existing script:

- Tap on big button with python logo in center of screen.
- Tap run local script.
- Tap on script you want to run.

http://wiki.qpython.org/doc/how-to-start/

edit: There is another app from same developers called Qpython3 in which you can run python3 applications including scripts and projects.In Qpython3 after running script it will take you to console for output instead of showing logfile in notification bar.

Answer (score 0):

It is same as Windows/Linux. You just have to be confident before trying something new. IMHO no one is professional at first try.
Please see video and let me know if you need further help.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UqlTErvbRdE
For long and deep understanding:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=So2weWysyZc

Answer (score 0):

I you know python 2(version).This will help.
http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting (the home of the SL4A project.)

This is by-far the best way you can run your Python app on android